# How to flash Dell Precision 390 from linux (debian)

Tags: debian, bios, dell-precision

I am trying to update my BIOS:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
2.1.2
```

With a newer one: 2.6.0. I went to this page [Dell Precision System BIOS, 2.6.0](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/vn/driverdetails?driverid=R187213)

After downloading the file `WS390-020600.BIN`, here is what it states:

```
$ ./WS390-020600.BIN --help
Usage: WS390-020600.BIN [options]
Options:
  --help                  Print this text.
  --version               Print package versions.
If no options, update the BIOS.
```

and

```
$ ./WS390-020600.BIN --version
Dell BIOS Update Installer 1.2
Copyright 2006 Dell Inc. All Rights Reserved.

./WS390-020600.BIN: 60: ./WS390-020600.BIN: ./flash: not found
```

Does anyone knows where this `flash` command can be found ?

Update: it looks like this is a self-extracting archive (need `bash` as per comment in header).

```
$ head -30 WS390-020600.BIN
[...]
Extract()
{
    tail -n +`awk '/^__ARC__/ { print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0` $0 | gzip -cd >$_PRG
```

So the `flash` command should have been auto-generated, however the above command does not appear to be running as original author intended. I do not see anything wrong with the command though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extractor actually does extract the `flash` binary, but it immediately removes it after trying to run it.  You're seeing the "not found" error because you're missing the 32-bit libraries needed to run it.  On Ubuntu 14.04, I was able to get a Dell BIOS updater to run by installing these libraries with:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```